# Return rows of the latest 'streak' of data

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

Given a simple table with the following data:

```
 id | result |   played   
----+--------+------------
  7 | L      | 2012-01-07
  6 | L      | 2012-01-06
  5 | L      | 2012-01-05
  4 | W      | 2012-01-04
  3 | W      | 2012-01-03
  2 | L      | 2012-01-02
  1 | W      | 2012-01-01
```

How would I write a query to return the lastest losing or winning streak of rows using PostgreSQL? In this case, I'm looking for a result of:

```
 id | result |   played   
----+--------+------------
  7 | L      | 2012-01-07
  6 | L      | 2012-01-06
  5 | L      | 2012-01-05
```

I'm guessing the answer is to use `lag()` and partition syntax, but I can't seem to nail it down.

Comment: Are the numbers in `id` sequential without holes? Or are the dates in `played`? What is your version of PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming (as you don't tell) that

- there are exactly two distinct values for `result`: `(W, L)`.
- `id` is sequential in the sense that the latest entry has the highest `id`.

This would do the job:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  id > (
    SELECT max(id)
    FROM   tbl
    GROUP  BY result
    ORDER  BY max(id)
    LIMIT  1
    );
```

This gets the latest id for `W` and `L`, the earlier of the two first. So a `LIMIT 1` gets the last entry of the opposite outcome. Rows with an `id` higher than that form the latest streak. Voilá.

Comment: Nice. I ended up dropping the assumption that the ids are in sequence by using the 'played' date field instead.